# Is a 125 amp service panel compatible with the 200 amp transfer switch?

Tags: generator

I want to install an 18 kw Generac standby generator with 200 amp automatic transfer switch to our 125 amp service panel.

Is the 125 amp service panel compatible with the 200 amp transfer switch?

Answer (score 7):

There is no problem with a 200A switch - that's more *capable* than needed, which is fine.

However, any time you have an *automatic* transfer, you need to make sure the generator is up to the task. An 18 kW generator is 18,000W/240V = 75A. Which means if your 125A panel is pulling 100A at the time of the transfer then the generator will be quickly overloaded and you will have problems.

While anything is *possible* - e.g., someone plugs in and turns on a 1500W space heater on every 15A general purpose receptacle circuit in the house - the normal way, which works remarkably well, to figure out how much power an entire house or a subpanel needs is an **NEC Load Calculation**. This takes into account:

- Size (square feet) of your house
- Required dedicated circuits (e.g., kitchen, bathroom)
- Water heater (if electric)
- Cooking appliances (gets complicated)
- Other major appliances, with different rules depending on the type of load
- EV charging and other extra loads

and comes up with a single number. That number is what you use to size your generator. If the Load Calculation is 75A or less then you're all set. If you Load Calculation is more than 75A then you have a few options:

- If the 125A panel is not the main panel, move some circuits off of this panel so they are never run on the generator.
- Larger generator.
- Some sort of load management system so that certain loads only run when you have utility power. But this can't require manual intervention because your switch is automatic.

Comment: Before you do a full-blown NEC calculation you can do a 2-minute cheapo version that might *rule out* this generator.   Just look at the name plates on all your large electrical appliances and add up their power use.  For example, 2 A/C compressors at 21A each, 2 A/C blowers at 8A each, a dryer at 23A .... that's already more than 18kW, you don't need the full calculation.  Just keep going that way, for *at least* all 240V devices.  If you remain under 75A you can do the full calc.

Comment: @jay613 Exception: Only need HEAT **or** A/C. If you have a heat pump then they are one & the same. But if you have A/C plus resistive heat then only count whichever one is larger. The other consideration - it gets complicated - is oven, cooktop, etc. - there are some significant discounts you get when treating everything as a group, though if nameplate ratings get you over 75A then even with the discounts you're in trouble because you still have to add general purpose square footage based and other things.

Comment: If it's normal in your house to run these things together you should count them!  If I didn't police it the bathroom floor heat would be running all summer with the A/C blowing down on it.  Happy feet trumps NEC leniencies.